# Git fsck: killed. Is my repo ok?

Tags: git

I have checked out chromium which is 10GB. I want to know whether my revision (c2f950943600932bdc56db1bde88161dca3e70a3) is ok. So I tried

```
$ git fsck
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
Killed
```

What does killed mean? How do I make sure my local copy is indeed equivalent to the revision. I understand git computes a hash and these are compared?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Killed` means death by `SIGKILL`, which is usually caused by someone running `kill -9 $PID` but in this case I suspect the Linux OOM Killer. `git-fsck` used up all your memory so the kernel killed it. Maybe you should add some swap space.

Browse the [oom](/questions/tagged/oom) category for related questions.